# Запрос на предыдущее значение определённой даты

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос:

```
select 
        type_room_rus, period,
        case 
            when type_room_rus is not null then sum(price) / sum(area) end as price_1g
    from pbi#12_everyweekly
    where status_kv = 'AVAILABLE'
    group by type_room_rus, period
    order by type_room_rus, period
```

Результат запроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать, чтобы справа создавалась колонка с данными из другой ячейки (предыдущего периода). Так например, в строке №2 будет справа от price_1g число из строки №1 и так далее.
Проще говоря [price_1g] - 1.

Comment: [`LAG() function`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @Akina "lag(price_1g, 1) over (order by num_month) prev", как в таком случае использовать price_1g, если ее нельзя, так как я создал ее через as

Comment: Не понял, а что мешает преобразовать Ваш запрос в CTE? а снаружи - применяйте оконную функцию.

Comment: @Akina, отлично, все работает, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

По итогу:

```
SELECT *, 
        LAG(price_1g, 1) OVER(ORDER BY num_month) AS prev
FROM
(
    SELECT type_room_rus,
            CASE WHEN type_room_rus IS NOT NULL THEN SUM(price) / SUM(area) END AS price_1g,
            period
    FROM pbi#12_everyweekly
    WHERE status_kv = 'AVAILABLE'
    GROUP BY type_room_rus, period
) AS Subquery
ORDER BY type_room_rus, period
```

Можно через CTE(если на MS SQL пишите), как Akina предлагает, а можно с подзапросом - это решение подойдёт большинству СУБД.